# What Golarion god of the dwarven pantheon dislikes hammers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, lore, religions-and-deities, golarion, dwarf

I've created a dwarven monk (Pathfinder First Edition) and I'm thinking about the story my character has. Dwarves are usually associated with axes or warhammers but that doesn't fit the theme of a monk.

I'd like to have a story-based reason why my character fights with fists. Something like "I follow god X who abolishes hammers for war because of their imprecision but drives me towards becoming a weapon, hard as stone."

Of course that god has to be lawful since I'm a monk.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Ok, i think our story will take place in Golarion, since Torag and Droskar have been part of the plot so far. According to [this site](https://pathfinder.fandom.com/wiki/Torag) and [this site](https://pathfinder.fandom.com/wiki/Pathfinder_campaign_setting) both are part of of the deities of Golarion.

Comment: Yeah, Torag and Droskar are Golarion deities, and *Hollow’s Last Hope* is set in Andoran, which is a nation on Golarion, so that pretty well clinches it.

Comment: @Philipp Please don't answer in comments, either partially or as a frame challenge. [We try not do that here.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Irori is pretty much perfect for you. Irori is Lawful Neutral, has unarmed strikes as his favored weapon, uses an open hand as his holy symbol, and *Dwarves of Golarion* explicitly notes that dwarves worship him “alongside their own pantheon.” So he’s not a dwarven god per se, but he is a god dwarves worship.

His religion is all about self-perfection, which ties in very nicely with a desire to eschew hammers or other weapons in favor of relying only on your own body.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, thank you very much!